# How can a getter function know if setter function was called?

Tags: c

I have written setter and getter APIs for certain members of a struct in C. I want the getter function to be called only if setter API was called. Otherwise, default values should be assigned to the members of the function. Is there a way to find out if the members of struct were assigned values or not?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to keep track of it yourself, C doesn't have any reflection magic.

Comment: Also note that this is very atypical and strange for C code.  Sometimes it's better just to do as the Roman's do instead of attempting to enforce paradigms paradigms which don't fit nicely.  Also, how would you stop me from circumventing your getters and setters anyway? I can still create one of your structs and set things as I like.  Better to just document how you expect your types to be used and move on to real problems.

Comment: Programmers are not idiots. Trust them. Tell them they shouldn't call the getter without the setter and if they do, it's their own problem.

Comment: Basically, what I meant was, can I add a default value to those members of the struct in case the setter is not called...

Comment: @Scranton You could provide a function that initializes the struct with default values. But then again there's no way to know if someone called that function. The convention in such cases is that you document that the function _must_ be called, and if that isn't done, the joke's on the user as his program fails into oblivion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to find out if the members of struct were assigned values or not ?

No. You would need to keep track of that yourself by a separate set of variables, or by initializing the values of the struct to values they normally cannot have(e.g. -1 , but in such a case, every piece of code would need to honor the convention of not using such special values doring normal usage)